# Setup domain for VueJS server on network

Tags: node.js, apache, vue.js, server, domain-name

I have a project that use a NodeJs server for back-end and VueJs for front-end.
I run the front-end server using this:

```
npm run serve
```

Now, I have a domain

> duduman.ro

And I want to set the domain for my app that runs on localhost:8080
I tried using apache, but i didn't succeed.(setting virtualhost)

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName duduman.ro
</VirtualHost>
```

I also tried to set a subdomain: app.duduman.ro for 8080 port, but calling "app.duduman.ro" return "Object not found" and calling "app.duduman.ro:8080" return "Invalid Host header".

PS: The port is forwarded correctly because external ip using port 8080 works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Heroku node.js app, it should solve your issues.

https://www.heroku.com/nodejs

For me is the easiest way to deploy.

Comment: Thank you, it's what I was looking for.

Comment: Please @AlexandruDuDu could you upvote the answer as well? I hope it helps people to distinguish the favorite ones in time

Comment: Done, sorry for this, I forgot to upvote it. Thanks again!